# Pushing news to Facebook works, but I'm required to log in first. How to automate login?

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I've got a custom built news page that can cross post articles to Facebook and twitter.   I'm using the Facebook SDK - everything works perfectly.  I'm able to add articles, delete articles and even post/delete events.

All of this happens under our company's FB account, however folks writing the articles are first taken to FB to log in (or the SDK asks for permission to post to their personal FB account if they are already logged in).   This is triggered by a call to getUser().

I've googled a bit on this, and find a lot of info on working with the current FB user's data/profile, but haven't found where to automatically log in with a specific FB account, prior to working with that account.

Is what I'm wanting possible with the SDK?  If so, can someone point me to some 411 on getting this accomplished, or reply here with some info?

EDIT:

Instead of downvoting, can someone reply back with some feedback? I don't mind deleting the question if it is not appropriate, but I'd like to see where I deviated first. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of downvoting, can someone reply back with some feedback?  I don't mind deleting the question if it is not appropriate, but I'd like to see where I deviated first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can auto login using facebook.  Either you log in everytime using a specific account.  Or you have 1 universal account and use offline access with that.  That way user A, user B and user C log in with an internal account and then use the offline access with the FB universal account to post to FB.

Hope that is clear.  :)

Comment: Would either account be specified in my application?  Right now I'm using getUser(), which is triggering facebook to ask for credentials (or permission to use whatever account is logged in at the time).  Automation is what I'm hoping for.. willing to create a dedicated account for it, if I can just do the deed in my application.

Comment: Look up offline access and things will be much clearer for you.  You'll be able to log into your own app using internal credentials and then use a specific FB account with offline access to post.

Answer (score 0):

If you need something more than `publish_stream`, then it's going to be a manual process for you to give your automation an extended 60 day user access token.

If you only need `publish_stream`, then you can publish at any time, even when the user is not present using an app access token. See Facebook's [permissions documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's
>   stream and to the streams of the user's friends. With this permission,
>   you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without
>   requiring offline_access. However, please note that Facebook
>   recommends a user-initiated sharing model.